how to visually indicate the highest correlations in a polychoric correlation matrix with highly correlated items across the board?
I have a 25-item likert style type scale and I am looking to reduce the scale. I just obtained a polychoric correlation matrix and noticed that the inter-item correlations are really high across the board, like most of them are above 0.8. I am using corrplot function in R to help me visualize the matrix, but when the correlations are so high, the default color scheme doesn't really work. I wonder if there's a way to indicate with color only the pairs with correlations >0.9 in the matrix? here is my code:
cor_matrix=lavCor(fit_model1f, ordered = TRUE, group = NULL, output = "cor")
round(cor_matrix, digits = 2)
corrplot(cor_matrix) # by default, method = 'circle'

this is what it looks like now
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/U4Bbi.png

You didn't provide a reprex: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Here is one using data from the ?lavCor help page:
library(lavaan)
library(corrplot)

HStext <- HolzingerSwineford1939[,c("x4","x5","x6")]
foo <- lavCor(HStext)
corrplot(foo) # all high

The col.lim= argument can restrict the range of the legend, but it needs to be used in conjunction with other arguments.  This doesn't work:
corrplot(foo, col.lim = c(.7, .75))

because by default, is.corr=TRUE, which means it still chooses the palette range from [-1, +1].  Setting is.corr=FALSE means it will base the palette range on the min/max observed values, but that still includes the 1s on the diagonal. Furthermore, the lowest correlation will appear invisible, so I would still recommend setting a lower col.lim= to make them all visible.
corrplot(foo, col.lim = c(.7, .75), is.corr = FALSE)

If necessary, you can set the diagonal missing, to have the range spread only across the observed correlations. But then it displays a question mark in each diagonal panel, which you can erase by providing a space-character (or any 1-2 characters of your choice).
diag(foo) <- NA
corrplot(foo, col.lim = c(.7, .75), is.corr = FALSE, na.label = " ")


Thanks for your response! I just tried it but got this message " color limits should cover matrix" so i removed the cor.lim = c(.7, .75) and it worked.

You need to inspect your own matrix to see what the range() of values are, then select an appropriate cor.lim= range yourself.
